# Two's complement 8-bit subtractor?

Tags: logic

Please help me! I've been asked to make a circuit using only Logic Gates to implement an 8-bit 2's complement subtractor.

I was thinking of somehow modifying an 8-bit adder, but I figured it isn't 2's complement so it won't be of much use to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated, even if it's a pointer to the right approach to take in this.

Comment: Being "2s complement" isn't a property of the adder, it is a proper of the encoding of number. A *binary* adder used with 2s complement encoded *numbers* can also do subtraction because a-b=a+(-b) and -b has a binary representation using 2s complement. You should reread your course or look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 2):

It may seem at first as though computing the two's complement of `b` would cost you a whole separate incrementer, but you can easily merge it into the adder that you need anyway: just set the carry-in.

Alternatively (for example if you are somehow forced to use an adder without carry-in, or if it just works out better in combination with other logic) you may used that `a - b = ~(~a + b)`, which obviously only ever needs inverters and a normal adder. This does put inverters before and after though, whereas to calculate the two's complement of `b` you'd only need inverters before the adder (and a carry-in but that's almost free).

Answer (score 1):

Subtraction $a-b$ can be implemented by computing the 2's complement $c$ of $b$ and then adding $a+c$. So to construct your circuit, combine a circuit which computes 2's complement with one that computes addition.